# Retrieve the GET query string parameters using Express

Tags: node.js, api, express

I seem to have troubles on getting the query string parameter on my Postman. 
First, I wanted to get all of the game types API by using the url of:

```
localhost:3000/api/gameType/dota2
```

Here is the code below:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const GameTypeRepository = require('../../repository/GameTypeRepository');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
try {
   const game_types = await GameTypeRepository.findByName(req.query.name);
   res.json(game_types);
 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
   res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

**GameTypeRepository.js**

```
  const BaseRepository = require('../../../shared/repository/BaseRepository');
  const GameType = require('../models/GameType');

  class GameTypeRepository extends BaseRepository {
     constructor(model) {
     super(model);
  }

     findByName(name, fields) {
       const options = {
       where: { name }
      };
      if (!!fields && fields) {
      options.attributes = fields;
      }
      return this.model.findOne(options);
    }
  }

  module.exports = new GameTypeRepository(GameType);
```

But when I execute the url to my Postman, I get this log on my terminal that says:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `description` FROM `game_types` AS `game_types` WHERE `game_types`.`id` = 'dota2';
```

Which should be `'name' = 'dota2'`

Any ideas on how to work with this? TYIA.

Comment: In your example URL `dota2` is a [route parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters), not a query param.

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out by using '/type' and changing the url to : http://localhost:3000/api/gameType/type?name=dota2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding **/type** in my `router.get('/type/:name,`

```
router.get('/type/:name', async (req, res) => {
try {
const game_types = await GameTypeRepository.findByName(req.params.name);
res.json(game_types);
 } catch (error) {
res.sendStatus(404);
 }
});
```